# summation values in structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, dimension

I have a *3*-by-*3*-by-*3* struct, `struct`, with fields `bit`. In each field I have two values. I want to divide values of each field by a summation of values of each field in dimension 3

for example if

```
struct(1,1,1).bit=[2, 3]

struct(1,1,2).bit=[4, 5]

struct(1,1,3).bit=[6, 7]
```

my new struct values must be for example:

```
newstruct(1,1,1).bit=[2/(2+4+6) ,  3/(3+5+7)]

newstruct(1,1,2).bit=[4/(2+4+6) ,  5/(3+5+7)]

newstruct(1,1,3).bit=[6/(2+4+6) ,  7/(3+5+7)]
```

Comment: I assume you want `2/(2+4+6)` and not `2/2+4+6`? Your code also misses `[]` when creating an array. The first line sets `bit` to `2`.

Comment: You also have to fix your indexing, that`s not a 3d-index. Third line indexes element 1 to 3 on the first dimension.

Comment: This is not code this is an example about 3 dimension of one field of my structure.

Comment: Using something which is syntactically m-code but it's no m-code to describe your example data does not make any sense. It's not clear what you really want. Is it `2/(2+4+6)` or `2/2+4+6`?

Comment: let explain more struct(1:1:1), struct(1:1:2)and struct(1:1:3) is 3 dimensions of field(1*1) of my original struct. each field of 18 fields of this struct has 2 values. and I want to create new struct based on this struct that each field of them is the value of field of old struct divided by summation of values in corresponding fields in dimenstion 3

Comment: This would be `struct(1,1,1)` `struct(1,1,2)` and `struct(1,1,3)`.

Comment: To add to Daniels explanation: `struct(1:1:3)` is equal to `struct([1 2 3])` and is not equal to `struct(1,1,3)`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't explain my intension.6 and 7 are values that are located in field named bit with location of (1,1,3) of my original struct.

Comment: I don't think you can index through multiple fields of a structure because MATLAB doesn't know _a priori_ that all fields have the same dimension and data type (see the comments in this [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/04/19/vectorizing-access-to-an-array-of-structures/)). As @LuisMendo has suggested in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962271/extract-values-from-structure-in-matlab), it would be a lot easier to do this with an nD array rather than a structure.

Answer (score 0):

As it is MATLAB, you should possibly go with an `nD` array instead of the `struct`.
Yet, if you still want to do it this way, don't fear the good old `for`-loop:

```
for d1 = 1:size(in,1)
    for d2 = 1:size(in,2)
        d3sum = sum(cat(1,in(d1,d2,:).bit),1);
        for d3 = 1:size(in,3)
            out(d1,d2,d3).bit = in(d1,d2,d3).bit./d3sum;
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is with a `for` loop, or to use nD arrays:

```
s(1,1,1).bit = [2 3];
s(1,1,2).bit = [4 5];
s(1,1,3).bit = [6 7];

[m,n,p] = size(s);
[mm,nn] = size(s(1,1,1).bit); % assume all elements of the structure have the same dimension
struct_sum = zeros(1,nn);

% compute the sums
for k=1:p
    struct_sum = struct_sum+s(1,1,k).bit;
end

% create the new stucture
for k=1:p
    s1(1,1,k).bit = s(1,1,k).bit./struct_sum;
end
```

**UPDATE**: option with nD array

```
s(1,1,1,1:2)=[2 3];
s(1,1,2,1:2)=[4 5];
s(1,1,3,1:2)=[6 7];
s1 = s./sum(s); % you can specify sum(s,3) to sum along the 3rd dimension - you may also need to use squeeze(...) to remove unnecessary dimensions
```

Check it gives the correct results:

```
>> s1(1,1,:,1)
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =  0.16667
ans(:,:,2) =  0.33333
ans(:,:,3) =  0.50000

>> [2 4 6]/12
ans =

   0.16667   0.33333   0.50000

>> s1(1,1,:,2)
ans =

ans(:,:,1) =  0.20000
ans(:,:,2) =  0.33333
ans(:,:,3) =  0.46667

>> [3 5 7]/15
ans =

   0.20000   0.33333   0.46667
```