# extract values from structure in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a question please if we have structure with 3 dimension and each field of them has 7 values how can extract each value from each field of this structure separately.

Comment: Could you explain little more about structure with 3 dimensions? Do you mean structure has 3 fields? It would be nice if you some example code to create structure you are referring.

Comment: no my structure is (3*3*3) with fields named bit. therefore my structure has 27 fields. in each field I have 7 values. I want to extract these values separately from these fields.

Comment: Why don't you give us an example of the structure? A link to a mat file or something.

Comment: for example if I write

Comment: for example struct(1,1,2).data=data:[1 2 3 5 6 0 9] or struct(1,1,3).data=data:[3 4 0 11 23 6 9]. but I want to with some changes in code when I call struct(1,1,3).data I can get 3 or 4 or 0 or 11 or 23 or 6 or 9 separately. because I want add each of them separately with corresponding values of field of other dimension of this struct

Answer (score 2):

Just use indexing:

```
>> s(1,1,1).data = [1 2 3 4];
>> s(1,1,2).data = [10 20 30 40 50]; %// example struct
>> s(1,1,2).data(3)
ans =
    30
>> s(1,1,2).data(2:4)
ans =
    20    30    40
```

Also, it's better not to use `struct` as a variable name, because `struct` is a built-in function.

Comment: However, if you try to do `s(1,1,:).data(1)`, you'll get an error (at least I do in octave). As far as I understand it, that's what the OP wants to do, particularly in light of his/her previous question on the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961332/summation-values-in-structure-in-matlab.

Comment: Than you Luis but I want the other thing. I found it:`for i=1:3
for j=1:3
for l=1:2
B=[strut(i,j,l).data]; end end end`.

Comment: @am304 I see. All of this would be much simpler using an ND-array instead of a structure

Comment: I am beginner but my data is structure and I need it at the next part of my code in structure form. I have to use structure. I don't know what is ND-array.